# Rails 4 safely using variables in "Where" method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, mysql2

I've rolled my own search for a Rails 4 app. Now I need to offer the user different columns to search on. I've created a dropdown menu within the view's search form as follows:

```
<%= form_tag manage_accounts_administrator_path, :method => 'get', :id => "search-form" do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Search Accounts' %>
      <%= select_tag("search_criteria", options_for_select([['by account number', '1'],['by customer id', '2'],['by customer name (ex: Jane Doe)', '3']])) %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

And then in the corresponding controller method, I'm doing this:

```
  def manage_accounts
    # criteria from the "Search by" select menu
    if params[:search]
        case (params[:search_criteria])
        when 1
          @criteria = id
        when 2
          @criteria = customer_id
        when 3 
          @criteria = customer.firstname + ' ' + customer.lastname
        end

        @accounts = Account.where("#{@criteria} LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per(15)
        @table_heading = "Account Search Results"
    else
        @accounts = Account.order('id').page(params[:page]).per(15)
        @table_heading = "Listing All Accounts"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html {render 'manage_accounts'}
    end
  end
```

The three possible values for the @criteria variable in the case block above represent fields of the "Account" model. As you can see, what I'm expecting to happen is for a query to be conducted using the "where" method. This syntax is wrong, and I get the error:

> **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Administrators#manage_accounts** Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'LIKE '%722586388%')' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `accounts`  WHERE ( LIKE '%722586388%')

Clearly I'm doing this wrong. **How can I interpolate the @criteria variable similar to how I interpolate the search param?** What the error shows me is that the variable is being escaped completely. I've tried (guessed) dozens of different punctuation combinations to no avail. I feel like this will work if I just get the syntax right.

Also, I've read that this is bad practice as it makes the app vulnerable to SQL injections. **How, then, should I write this statement in a secure manner?**

Thank you

It's rails 4.1.8 with MySQL2 gem and I am noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to surround your variables with quotes. When execution hits the line

```
@accounts = Account.where("#{@criteria} LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

`@criteria` will still be `nil`. So the sql generated by activerecord will be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  accounts WHERE ( LIKE '%722586388%')` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  accounts WHERE (id LIKE '%722586388%')`, for instance.

So inside your case you will have to something like:

```
if params[:search]
    case (params[:search_criteria])
    when 1
      @criteria = 'id'
    when 2
      @criteria = 'customer_id'
    when 3 
      @criteria = 'customer.firstname'
    end
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Tried with single and double quotes.

Comment: What are the vales of `params[:search]` and `params[:search_criteria]`?

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem. The value of `params[:search]` is correct as what was entered on the text field. However, `params[:search_criteria]` is **nil**. Something is wrong, apparently with my _select_ tag_. I don't know what it could be. I'm not used to the form_tag way of doing this. Not sure but apparently nothing's being passed to controller from the select menu.

Comment: If is not `1`, `2` nor `3`, `@criteria` will be `nil` and your SQL Query will me malformed.

Comment: I got it! Since my options for select_tag were in quotes ('1', '2', and '3'), the _when_ parameters in my "case" block also needed quotes. For example, `when '1' .. @criteria = "id"`. Now everything works great! Thanks for your help with this noob mistake. Marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if params[:search]
    case (params[:search_criteria])
    when 1
      @criteria = "id"
    when 2
      #assuming you have a customer_id column in your accounts table
      @criteria = "customer_id"
    when 3 
      #assuming you have a customer_name column in your accounts table
      @criteria = "customer_name"
    end
```